# Create an Array of Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic-arrays

I want to create this structure dynamically in Javascript:

```
var myCols = [
  {data1: 'A', data2: '0', data3: 1},
  {data1: 'B', data2: '1', data3: 1},
  {data1: 'C', data2: '2', data3: 1}
];
```

How can I do this?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: You just did. What's the problem with it?

Comment: are the keys and values dynamic ?

Comment: You can change anything in the array you just created at any time. Like this for example: `myCols[0].data1 = "New value";`

Comment: @j08691 No, that's source code - it's static. Dynamic creation would be a function which is invoked with some arguments, and which return value is the object.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - actually the problem is that the question is poorly worded.

Comment: Thanks to all. I have JSON File that all of data comes from there. Maybe data1, data2, data3, data4, ... and Maybe 5,6 or 7 rows. And I have to create them with this structure Dynamically.

Comment: @Natasha You can use `JSON.parse` (and json2.js on older browsers if you support them). `var myCols = JSON.parse(my_json_data);` will do everything you need.

Comment: @Natasha json2.js can be downloaded from here. https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js With it included in a script tag before your script that you need it in you can use `JSON.parse` in older browsers. Without that script included it will still work in modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you PaulP.R.O. You've Been A Big Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague. There are infinitely many ways to generate that dynamically. How you do it depends on the data you start with and how and when you want to create it. For example you could generate exactly that above code dynamically on the server side after a DB query, or you could generate it with something like this loop, which would go own through more letters in data1 and more numbers (as strings) in data2 if you increase 3 to something less than or equal to 26.

```
var myCols = [];
var myData, i;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    myData = {};
    myData.data1 = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
    myData.data2 = "" + i;
    myData.data3 = 1;

    myCols.push(myData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Use push to add items "dynamically" to an array.

```
// Create empty array
var myCols = [];

// Add items at a later time to the array using push
myCols.push( {data1: 'A', data2: '0', data3: 1});
// ... (repeat pushing more items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use push method of array object you can use it like

var anarr = [] or var anarr = new Array();

and then you can push elements to array one by one using

anarr.push(value);

where value can be anything.

Try to understand following code.

```
var keys = ['data1','data2','data3'];
var arr = new Array();

    function add(a,b,c){
        temp_dict = {}
        temp_dict[keys[0]]=a
        temp_dict[keys[1]]=b
        temp_dict[keys[2]]=c
        arr.push(temp_dict);
    }
        add('A','0',1);
        add('B','1',1);
        add('C','2',1);
        console.log(arr);
```